Software that can backup files FROM cloud storage
I need a software that can be granted permission to access cloud storage accounts, get files that user specifies, and then make local backups of said files on a regular basis.
I'm primarily concerned with Google Photos, so if said software is mainly used for photos/image files it's perfectly fine. It would also be nice if the software can make incremental backup like DejaDup/Duplicity.
The closest thing I know is Google Drive app for desktop, but this doesn't support Linux, and is more geared towards getting your photos into Google Photos rather than the other way around.

It sounds like you require Linux support.  Is this correct?

@EndAntisemiticHate A multi-platform support would be great, but I plan to run this on a regular basis in a Linux-based home server.

Sounds good.  I'll add the Linux tag for you.

Below I can think of:
Rclone - Open-source, can sync files from Google Photos or Drive to local storage with incremental backups. Compatible with Linux.
BDRSuite - Good for taking a backup of your Google Drive or Microsoft OneDrive files locally. Supports incremental backups and M365/GWS.

Please link the product's official websites so that we can easily find out more about them. Next, please post one answer per product, so that people can vote on the products individually.
